# Custom menu with Walker class - what should the $db_fields be?

Tags: menus, walker

I'm trying to create my own custom menu using the Walker class and in the process of trying to figure out what's going on, I'm attempting to reproduce what wp_nav_menu() does by default, so, I've got this:

```
class My_Admin_Walker extends Walker
{
    public $db_fields = array ('parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'menu_id');
}

function my_admin(  ){
   //$list = wp_nav_menu( array( 'walker' => new My_Admin_Walker() ));//produces no output 
   //$list = wp_nav_menu();//outputs links to pages

   return $list;
}

 my_admin();
```

When I pass my own `My_Admin_Walker` class to `wp_nav_menu` it produces no output. So I think I need to set the required `$db_fields` to something. The Walker docs say:

> *The value of each key should be the names of the object properties that hold the parent id and item id, respectively.*

But I'm stuck on figuring out what the `$db_fields` should be set to, to produce the default output or any other output. I've tried field names in the wp database but had no luck so far. Where do I look up these object properties it's talking about?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build your own custom nav menu you should be extending the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class, not the `Walker` class.

When building a custom menu walker the `$db_fields` should be what the default `Walker_Nav_Menu` class has:

```
$db_fields = array ('parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id');
```

When building the navigation link for a menu item, the `parent` field maps to the `_menu_item_menu_item_parent` post meta field if the menu item has a parent.

The `db_id` maps to the post `ID` of the menu item.

Check out `wp_setup_nav_menu_item()` for good reference to better understand what is happening. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_setup_nav_menu_item/

Comment: Many thanks for your answer I shall check out those docs. Do you happen to know if the `Walker_Nav_Menu` can de used to customise the nav menu in the Admin interface?

Comment: The navigation menu in the sidebar of the admin?  `Walker_Nav_Menu` isn't used to build that.  The `Walker_Nav_Menu` class is used to build navigation menus based on what you set in Appearance -> Menus.  This is because it uses the `nav_menu_item` post_type to build them.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know how I can alter the admin menu? In particular I'm wanting to add something to the html title attribute.